# How to determine a "width" of string in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a input box which it's for email accounts, it's bg-image is "@mydomain.com" positioned in right, and user could make their own email account in my system.

After they typed their user, for example "behzad", I want to the bg-image of the input comes in left and fill the empty space if there is.

For example, someone types "x" for the user name, and because the "@mydomain.com" is positioned in right, there is lots of free space between "x" and "@mydomain.com", it's like "x(SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE...)@mydomain.com" I want that on blur of that input box, it goes like this "x@mydomain.com".

```
$('#email-input').blur(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'new_position')
});
```

How 'new_position' could be determined based by the user input string width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I figured this out:

```
$('#username').blur(function(){
    var user_input = $('#username').val();
    $(this).removeClass('email-input');
    $('#username').val(user_input+'@mydomain.com');
});
```

no free space, and also I get what I wanted without determining the string width.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: So flag this as the answer if that is what you want to use (see below).

Answer (score 3):

I personally like Twitter Bootstrap's approach to this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/QvR6f/2/

Instead of using a background image, just stick another element to the end of your text box.

Comment: Still lots of free space and looks bad, is it so hard that even Google left it like this? try to create a new account in Gmail, they even couldn't get rid of the free space on their inputbox...

Comment: +1, nice solution, and if OP doesn't like the spacing, applying `text-align: right` to the input solves that issue too. One might even be able to use a auto-sizing input box. Well done.

Comment: @behz4d: I'm pretty sure Google and Twitter know what they're doing in terms of UX design, but if you don't like my solution, don't use it. I'm just offering it as a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a hidden page element that has the same font, size, etc. as the input box. You set its content to the text the user wrote and then read its width.

**Edit:**

Here is an example of this technique: http://www.easyjquery.com/onload-fit-input-size-to-length-of-text/

```
  function resizeIt(field) {
    var measure = $("#measure");
    measure.text(field.val());
    field.css("width", (measure.width() + 16) + "px");
  }
```

`measure` would be a span in your document with the same formatting as input box. `field` is your input box.

Also I was thinking maybe instead of using the background image of the input box, I would position it beside the input box, so that if the user writes a really long string it doesn't "overwrite" the domain name.

Comment: Good idea, how about hiding the bg-image on blur and change the whole .text of the input box '+@mydomain.com? it's better I guess

Comment: But keep in mind that the user may want to edit the field again, so you would need to remove the text again when it gets focus. Not sure if it works good, you should test it.